# Programmatically creating custom cells in objective c?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, cell-formatting

I'm having issues getting customs cells to show up. Below I've posted a simplified version of my code:

```
 - (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyle)style reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier {
    self = [super initWithStyle:style reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier];

    NSLog(@"Being Called?");
    //reuseID = @"newtableid";
    self.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];

    self.name = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.width, 50)];
    self.name.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];

    [self addSubview:self.name];

    return self;
}
```

In my viewController, I set up the tableView in the ViewDidLoad method:

```
 self.table = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 100, [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.width, 400) style:UITableViewStylePlain];

 self.table.delegate = self;
 self.table.dataSource = self;
 self.table.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];

 [self.view addSubview:self.table];
 [self.table registerClass:NewTableViewCell.class forCellReuseIdentifier:@"Cell"];
```

Then, I complete the cellForRowAt method like so:

```
 - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    static NSString *simpleTableIdentifier = @"Cell";

    NewTableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[NewTableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];
}

    cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];

    cell.name.text = [_familyDetails objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    return cell;
}
```

The problem is, I don't get anything to show up on my cells. My NewTableVIewCell constructor is called, but the cells show up blank (without color, label, etc.) What am I doing wrong?

Comment: "Programmatically creating custom cells" in the question, and yet I thin that `(void)awakeFromNib` is from the `NewTableViewCell` class? Where do we see the `initWithStyle:reuseIdentifier:` code of it?

Comment: Did you implement numberOfRows and heightForRows from tableview delegate method into your viewController ?

Answer (score 5):

If you're creating the cell programatically, make sure you register your cell to your table view.

```
[self.tableView registerClass:UITableViewCell.class forCellReuseIdentifier:"yourCellId"];
```

I am using a generic `UITableViewCell` in this case. You can try to change the text label of it in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` to see whether that works.

Be sure to change it to your custom cell class if needed.

Answer (score 1):

In order to `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier`, you have to use

```
- (void)registerClass:(Class)cellClass 
forCellReuseIdentifier:(NSString *)identifier
```

and normally you will not even have to instantiate `NewTableViewCell` if you use `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:forIndexPath:`. However, if you still use `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:` then you still need to instantiate your cell subclass (thanks  for reminding me [Alejandro Ivan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1986221/alejandro-iv%C3%A1n)).

EDIT: So you have to write something like this, in your `viewDidLoad` for example :

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    // Your stuff...
    [self.table registerClass:[NewTableViewCell class] forCellReuseIdentifier: simpleTableIdentifier];
}
```

Comment: He needs to instantiate it if he's using `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:` (as he's doing right now). That method could return `nil` and crash his app. Only `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:forIndexPath:` ensures you won't get `nil`.

Comment: Oh yes you're right! Forgot that part (my bad for using Storyboard and forgetting about this).